# Can a single in App purchase item be linked to multiple items

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

The application I'm developing has multiple MP3's for purchase and download. I need to know if I have to create "In-App Purchase" items for each of the MP3 items. (Each MP3 item can be priced differently, but multiple MP3s can have the same price ). Please advise on this.

Comment: These would be non-consumable purchases and these can only be purchased once (after that if the user attempts to purchase the same in-app product again, they get it for free), so you would need one IAP product per MP3.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead with consumable purchases with this case. You would need to create different priced products on itunes.
So lets say there are two price variants in your app. 10rs/song and 15rs/song.

So while displaying songs you can show appropriate itunes product with them. When user purchases a song, record the transaction on your server as well, that way you will be able to track how many songs are bought by one user. And you can give access to those mp3 on other device as well if user logs in with same user id.